# error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[6]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I have created a function that returns the sum of all the numbers in an array, however I keep getting an error message: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[6]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]. In addition I also get an error that says: error: initializing argument 1 of 'int getTotal(int)'[-fpermissive]. It seems like these two errors go together. Am I supposed to use pointers? I have spent hours trying to figure this out with no luck.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    const int ROWS = 4;
    const int COLS = 6;

    void openInputFile(ifstream &,string);
    int getTotal(int);

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int tot; //total of all numbers
        int val;
        int twoArray[ROWS][COLS];
        ifstream inFile;
        string inFileName = "nums.txt";

        //Opening file
        openInputFile(inFile, inFileName);

        //Create 2D array
        for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
            {
                inFile >> twoArray[i][j];
            }
        }

        //Close
        inFile.close();

        //THIS IS WHERE ERROR IS
        tot = getTotal(twoArray);

        printArray(twoArray);


        return 0;
    }

    void openInputFile(ifstream &inFile, string theFile)
    {
        inFile.open(theFile.c_str());

        if(!inFile)
        {
            cout << "Error opening the file!\n";
            exit(13);
        }
     }

    int getTotal(int array[][COLS])
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
            {
                sum+=array[i][j];
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }


    int printArray(int array[][COLS])
    {
            for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
            {
                cout << array[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: adjust `int getTotal(int);` at the top to `int getTotal(int **);` or something similar

Comment: @jhnnslschnr, `int**` is not the same as `int(*)[6]` at all.

Comment: This is already done (apparently) correctly for `printArray` (which is missing a function prototype, btw) using a `int arr[][COLS]` parameter. So.. what is the problem with doing the same thing with `getTotal` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig cant believe I didnt even notice this what a stupid mistake. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in wrong function declaration. You have at the beginning of code:

```
  int getTotal(int);
```

and then define function as:

```
  int getTotal(int array[][COLS])
```

So, edit your functions' declaration. By the way I cannot see declaration for:

```
  int printArray(int array[][COLS]);
```